# Recursive approach for pow(x,n) for finding 2^(37) with less than 10 multiplications

Tags: recursion

The regular recursive approach for pow(x,n) is as follows:

pow (x,n):

```
     = 1 ...n=0

     = 0 ...x=0

     = x ...n=1

     = x * pow (x, n-1) ...n>0
```

With this approach 2^(37) will require 37 multiplications. How do I modify this to reduces the number of multiplications to less than 10? I think this could be done only if the function is not excessive.

Comment: Note that x**n=(x**n/2)**2 when n is even, or that times x when n is odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this approach you can compute 2^(37) with only **7 multiplications**.

pow(x,n):

```
    = 1 ... n=0

    = 0 ... x=0

    = x ... n=1

    = pow(x,n/2) * pow (x,n/2) ... n = even

    = x * pow(x,n/2) * pow(x,n.2) ... n = odd
```

Now lets calculate 2^(37) with this approach -

2^(37) =

```
     = 2 * 2^(18) * 2^(18)

     =              2^(9) * 2^(9)

     =                      2 * 2^(4) * 2^(4)

     =                                  2^(2) * 2^(2)

     =                                          2 * 2
```

This function is not excessive and hence it reuses the values once calculated. Thus only 7 multiplications are required to calculate 2^(37).

Comment: Are you invoking the `pow` function twice on the n even/odd lines?

Comment: @pjs yes, made use of recursion

Comment: Then you're mistaken when you state that you calculate the result in 7 multiplications.  By doubling the number of recursive calls at each level, you undo the work of cutting the exponent in half. If you don't believe the logic of it, try implementing it and count. You'll find that your current algorithm actually does 36 multiplications.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the power of a number in logN time instead of linear time.

```
int cnt = 0;

// calculate a^b
int pow(int a, int b){
    if(b==0) return 1;
    if(b%2==0){
        int v = pow(a, b/2);
        cnt += 1;
        return v*v;
    }else{
        int v = pow(a, b/2);
        cnt += 2;
        return v*v*a;        
    }
}
```

Number of multiplications will be 9 for the above code as verified by [this](http://ideone.com/oOEZx8) program.

Comment: This does the correct number of recursive calls because the arithmetic on `b` is right, but the actual power calculation overflows a Java `int` when attempting powers bigger than 30.

Answer (score 1):

Doing it slightly differently than invin did, I come up with 8 multiplications.  Here's a Ruby implementation.  Be aware that Ruby methods return the result of the last expression evaluated.  With that understanding, it reads pretty much like pseudo-code except you can actually run it:

```
$count = 0

def pow(a, b)
  if b > 0
    $count += 1    # note only one multiplication in both of the following cases
    if b.even?
      x = pow(a, b/2)
      x * x
    else
      a * pow(a, b-1)
    end
  else             # no multiplication for the base case
    1
  end
end

p pow(2, 37)       # 137438953472
p $count           # 8
```

Note that the sequence of powers with which the method gets invoked is

```
37 -> 36 -> 18 -> 9 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0
```

and that each arrow represents one multiplication. Calculating the zero<sup>th</sup> power always yields 1, with no multiplication, and there are 8 arrows.

Since x<sup>n</sup> = (x<sup>n/2</sup>)<sup>2</sup> = (x<sup>2</sup>)<sup>n/2</sup> for even values of n, we can derive this subtly different implementation:

```
$count = 0

def pow(a, b)
  if b > 1
    if b.even?
      $count += 1
      pow(a * a, b/2)
    else
      $count += 2
      a * pow(a * a, b/2)
    end
  elsif b > 0
    a
  else
    1
  end
end

p pow(2, 37)       # 137438953472
p $count           # 7
```

This version includes all of the base cases in the original question, it's easy to run and confirm that it calculates 2^37 in 7 multiplications, and doesn't require any allocation of local variables.  For production use you would, of course, comment out or remove the references to `$count`.